# Visual Studio Team Services build process cannot find CSharp targets file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to set up a build process in Visual Studio Team Services, and I've done so by following the steps for [**UWP projects**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/apps/universal) using an [**agent**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows) on my box, but I keep getting the following build errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v12.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets(7,3): Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v12.0\10.0.10240.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

I checked out the path the build is complaining about and the problem is in the 10.0.10240.0 in the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v12.0\10.0.10240.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets
```

The target file is located in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v12.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets
```

Here is how the  declaration in the project file looks like (I don't think it is erroneous and I don't see where this weird 10.0.10240.0 version comes from in the path):

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" />
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Universal Windows Platform was introduced in Windows 10. Visual Studio has support for UWP apps as of Visual Studio 2015. You need to use VS2015 to create a UWP project, and install VS2015 on your build agent machine.

Comment: I never use VS 2015 to build this project, only VS 2013. I find it strange that VS TS needs VS 2015. I will try and get back to you.